# Nifi GetTwitter Processors with Proxy

Tags: proxy, apache-nifi

I am using NiFi at work. I'm behind the proxy. I can't get data from twitter because of error **cannot establish connection properly** and **connect time out**

Did someone what I have to do to fix this error? Or maybe someone know the configuration for GetTwitter Processor with Proxy?

Thanks

Comment: Can you copy and paste the error generated when you turn the processor on ?

Answer (score 0):

The latest release of the underlying library used by the GetTwitter processor [doesn't support proxies](https://github.com/twitter/hbc/issues/90) (even though the latest code does). There's a [custom processor](https://github.com/simonellistonball/nifi-GetTwitterWithProxy) available that supports a proxy.